# How count date row using aqua data studio

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

i want to ask, how to count date row  when data is null using aqua data studio.

For example

```
select 
convert(varchar(10),dateclosed,103)
from customer
where dateclosed = '(null)'


no.  dateclosed    count(dateclosed)
1     1/1/2001         2
2.    1/1/2001
3.    2/1/2001         1
4.    3/1/2001         1
5.    (null)           4      
6.    (null)         
8.    (null)
9.    (null)
10.    5/1/2001         3
11.    5/1/2001
12.    5/1/2001
13.    6/1/2001         1
```

Comment: i want to  count table have value "(null)" per row. if one row got the data 2,9,7 and other value. not a total count

Comment: i'm sorry because i mistakes to put the null value.i have updated my table. Hope you can see the table. i have put the value "null". i just want to count like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aggregate functions (except for `COUNT(*)`) ignore the NULL values, so you need to:

- use `COUNT(*)` (instead of `COUNT(expression)`)
  **OR**
- convert all the NULL values to some characteristic date:

  ```
  SELECT ISNULL(dateclosed, '1900-01-01'), count(ISNULL(dateclosed, '1900-01-01'))
  FROM customer
  GROUP BY ISNULL(dateclosed, '1900-01-01')
  ```

Comment: i get the answer.Thank you very much.@Marek Grzenkowicz:)